# send messages between 2 asp.net web applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I have 2 web forms applications written in c# asp.net. This is the kind of thing I need:

1. A  user clicks a button in web app 1
2. Web app 1 needs to send some parameters to web app 2 and get a response
3. Web app 1 uses the response from web app 2 to finish processing the post-back
4. User is happy

So I guess I need to incorporate some kind of web service thing into my web applications? Please point me in the right direction.

**Update:**

I've done some more research and found that WCF seems to be a goer. I have used WCF once before (stumbled through it) but how do I use WCF inside a web application - or do I need to create another application just for WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inter-process communication is a pretty large topic and there are many ways to do it.

Some tings to consider are

1. Synchronous vs Asynchronous - What should be the behavior if the user clicks the button twice in quick succession?
2. What should happen if user clicks the button but the web app2 is down for a few minutes?
3. Authorization and security
4. Denial Of Service style attacks

For something of this nature I would be inclined to use something like a message-queue maybe managed by something like [nservicebus](http://nservicebus.com/) it would be a very simple, yet robust solution. WCF is another option and so is MVC 4.0 web services.

Comment: Thanks; they are things I hadn't considered. I was about go all-out researching WCF and just 'get something working' but I turned to stackoverflow for some advice and now I'm going to re-think my implementation.